# How to pass Events from Model to ViewModel in WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my class I registered an `Event` from an external DLL, that will be raised when there are changes on variables from the external code.

```
public class Model
{
   ....
   public void Connect
   {
    ....
    client.OnNotification += (s, e) =>
    {
       this.OnNotification(s,e);
    }
   }
}
```

And I have a `ViewModel` in which I want get notified when this event is raised in class `Model`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
  ...
  // call method when Event in class Model is raised
  public void DoSomething()
  {
  }
}
```

Any Ideas for a clean and easy way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Pass in the client to the viewmodel's constructor and let the viewmodel subscribe to OnNotification() itself (pass in an interface if available)

**Solution 2:**
Make also the model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you're using MVVM; pass in the interface into the viewmodel's constructor and subscribe to `PropertyChanged`.

If you're not using MVVM, you can use the same methodology by adding a custom `ClientNotification` event to the model, pass in the entire model into the viewmodels constructor, and subscribe to the event.

**Solution 3:**
Use a messaging system (aka message bus) such as Prism's [Event Aggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) class or MVVM Light's [Messenger](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger) class, or write your own.

**EDIT: Here's an example using MVVM Light:** (note: coding from memory, not tested)

Add a using reference to `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging`;

Create a small message class containing the properties you need. You can inherit from MVVM Light's [MessageBase](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/ede9b0e1-636e-044c-8ba0-5905c7dcfaaf.htm) class if you want but its not necessary.

```
public class ClientNotificationMessage : MessageBase
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set;}
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set;}
}
```

In you model's event handler, you send a message by:

```
client.OnNotification += (s, e) =>
{
   var msg = new ClientNotificationMessage() { ... };
   Messenger.Default.Send<ClientNotificationMessage>(msg);
}
```

In the viewmodel constructor, register to receive messages by:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<ClientNotificationMessage>(this, msg => 
{
    // handle incoming ClientNotificationMessage
    // if (msg.SomeProperty != ) ...
});
```

I'm sure there are other additional solutions that other ppl can add.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is basic OOP design and it is not related to MVVM.

In C# you just don't pass events. You subscribe to events. Whenever something interesting happens in Model, fire en event. You can than subscribe to that event in ViewModel for example.

```
public class Model
{
   public event EventHandler SomethingHappened; // e.g. you notification
}

public class ViewModel
{
   public ViewModel(Model model)
   {
       model.SomethingHappend += SomethingHappend;
   }

   void Model_SomethingHappend(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      DoSomething();
   }


   void CleanUp()
   {
       /*
          In order to prevent memoryleak:
          If you subscribe to event of an object you have not created in this class 
          (Model.SomethingHappend in this case), you should also unsubscribe. 
          Otherwise model instance will keep reference to ViewModel instance. 
       */

       model.SomethingHappend -= SomethingHappend;
   }
}
```

In your case, the event could be named `NotificationRecieved` instead of SomethingHappend

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the event directly in the object you want to "react" to the event.

The viewModel in this case. Define an EventHandler there and subscribe